# On hover move text if width > 420

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make when you hover div **article_head**, check **span** width and if it is bigger then 420px(parrent div width - article_head) move text to see it whole. I know, it a little bit complicated...

> **Example:**
>
> > [image]
>
> Now, when you hover "How to install Windows..." it will move text and show
>
> > [image]

```
<div class="article_head"><span>Text with bigger width than 420px</span></div>

.article_head span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 110% !important;
    text-transform: none !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.article_head{
    line-height: 110% !important;
    margin:-10px 0 10px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:420px
}
```

I tried few times but without success...

Comment: @ZachSaucier I tried to do something in js but span width is always equal to parent width and it's never bigger than parent width. So when i write if width>420 it's never true because span width is always equal to 420px and it doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **[this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2pgZ/)** :

```
<div class="article_head">
    <span>Now, when you hover "How to install Windows..." it will move text and show Now, when you hover "How to install Windows..." it will move text and show </span>
<div>
```

## CSS

Add position:relative for Article Head

```
body {padding:20px;}
.article_head span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 110% !important;
    text-transform: none !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
.article_head{
    line-height: 110% !important;
    margin:-10px 0 10px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:420px
}
```

## jQuery

you may also add easing like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2pgZ/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.article_head').each(function () {
        var head_width = $(this).width();
        var span_width = $(this).find('span').innerWidth();
            $('.article_head').hover(function () {
        if (span_width > head_width) { 
            $(this).find('span').stop().animate({ 'right': head_width });
        }
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('span').stop().animate({ 'right': '0px' });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Vlada903 : I have added the jQuery Easing for you on the fuddle example above ... good luck

Comment: Thank you...this helped me alot. I changed a part of the code and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to use the `.scrollLeft` method to scroll inside the article head. You can calculate the maximum scroll position by evaluating `htmlElement.scrollWidth - htmlElement.clientWidth`

So you can implement two functions:
one to scroll to the right:

```
function move(htmlElement) {
    console.log(htmlElement);
    htmlElement.scrollLeft = htmlElement.scrollWidth - htmlElement.clientWidth;
}
```

and a function to reset the scroll position:

```
function moveBack(htmlElement) {
    htmlElement.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ysP7/

Comment: Is there any way to animate this and can i used it like this:

$('.article_head').hover(...)

because i have more than one div with text...

Comment: Thank you, it's working and i only want to know can i animate this?